# Powershell file name check

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need verify a file copied to a destination exists, the file format is like:

**SuperFile_yyyyMMdd_randomstring.txt**

What I have tried to do is the below:

`$FileDate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd`
`$FileExists = (Test-Path "\\UNC\TestShare\SuperFile_$FileDate_*")`

However all files that match the first part ***SuperFile_*** are copied and not just the ones matching the date. This file is created daily and I want to ignore any other file that do not contain the today's date. I had tried to do a Get-ChildItem query and pipe this into my check but it never returned any files.

So my problem is both copying and also verifying the file I just copied exists in the destination.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_` is a valid character for variable names, so the expression evaluated `$FileDate_`, which is not defined. This can be prevented by using a subexpression:

```
$FileDate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
$FileExists = (Test-Path "\\UNC\TestShare\SuperFile_$($FileDate)_*")
```

or by putting the variable name in curly braces:

```
$FileDate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
$FileExists = (Test-Path "\\UNC\TestShare\SuperFile_${FileDate}_*")
```